# R: re-arrange dataframe columns based on factor

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

Suppose I have a dataframe of values:

```
exp <- as.factor(c(rep('UT',3),rep('NC',3),rep('PC',3)))
fact <- as.factor(rep(c('A','B','C'),3))
set.seed(10)
avg <- rnorm(9,10,1)
sd <- rnorm(9,2,0.5)
df <- data.frame(exp,fact,avg,sd)
```

So df has three experimental treatments, with factors A-C, each with avg and sd.

```
  exp fact       avg       sd
1  UT    A 10.018746 1.871761
2  UT    B  9.815747 2.550890
3  UT    C  8.628669 2.377891
4  NC    A  9.400832 1.880883
5  NC    B 10.294545 2.493722
6  NC    C 10.389794 2.370695
7  PC    A  8.791924 2.044674
8  PC    B  9.636324 1.522528
9  PC    C  8.373327 1.902425
```

Is there an efficient way to re-arrange the dataframe in this way:

```
[1] "exp"   "A.avg" "A.sd"  "B.avg" "B.sd"  "C.avg" "C.sd"
```

In this case, we'd have just 3 rows, one for each treatment.

I suspect the solution lies with dplyr or tidyverse...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An approach using `reshape`

```
reshape(df, timevar="fact", idvar="exp", direction="wide")
  exp     avg.A     sd.A     avg.B     sd.B     avg.C     sd.C
1  UT 10.018746 1.871761  9.815747 2.550890  8.628669 2.377891
4  NC  9.400832 1.880883 10.294545 2.493722 10.389794 2.370695
7  PC  8.791924 2.044674  9.636324 1.522528  8.373327 1.902425
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tidyr::pivot_wider`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)


df %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = fact,
              values_from = c(avg, sd),
              names_glue = "{fact}.{.value}")  

#------
# A tibble: 3 x 7
  exp   A.avg B.avg C.avg  A.sd  B.sd  C.sd
  <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 UT    10.0   9.82  8.63  1.87  2.55  2.38
2 NC     9.40 10.3  10.4   1.88  2.49  2.37
3 PC     8.79  9.64  8.37  2.04  1.52  1.90
```

Answer (score 1):

alternatively

```r
df %>% pivot_longer(c(avg,sd)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = exp, names_from = c(fact,name), values_from = value, names_sep = '.')
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

```r
# A tibble: 3 × 7
  exp   A.avg  A.sd B.avg  B.sd C.avg  C.sd
  <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 UT    10.0   1.87  9.82  2.55  8.63  2.38
2 NC     9.40  1.88 10.3   2.49 10.4   2.37
3 PC     8.79  2.04  9.64  1.52  8.37  1.90
```